# Native implementation of an abstract method

Tags: java, java-native-interface, abstract-class

Is it permitted in Java to have a an abstract method within a class and then have it's implementation in an other with a native language using JNI.

example:

```
abstract class Mommy {
abstract protected void call();
}
class Son extends Mommy {
 native protected void call() /*
'native code'
*/
}
```

What is the expected behaviour is it a runtime error that may occurs or everything is fine with "workaround" ?

Comment: Have you tried this?

Comment: Of course, it goes through the compilation process but i wonder if bug prone or against any good/best practices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the expected behaviour is it a runtime error that may occurs or everything is fine with "workaround" ?

Provided that you implement the native method (correctly) and load the native library containing the implementation, then everything works.

> I wonder if bug prone or against any good/best practices?

Nope, and nope.

Or at least, it is not *more* bug prone or *more* against "best practice" than any use of native code.

By the way, you really ought to read [James Bach's "No Best Practices" article](http://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/27) before you bandy around dodgy terms like "best practice".

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working just fine. This is quite cool solution in case you want to easily switch between native implementations.

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo030

and description inside JNI Cookbook can give you quick overview on the solution

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-no-030/